# Moment JS fromNow Returning Same Value 'A Year Ago' for All Dates in a Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm working with eBay api and trying to turn the endTime field which is in a dateTime format into a field that shows how much time is left in an auction, such as 5 minutes or 5 hours or 5 days.

In node, i'm making call to eBay api and mapping the endTime field into a variable, using the moment function.

It looks like this:

```
var moment = require("moment");
moment().format();

const cardsData = newData.map(card => ({
timeLeft: moment(
          card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime
        ).fromNow()
```

Every value in the loop is returning 'a year ago'.

This is what the actual endTime field looks like

```
endTime: [
"2019-12-25T18:37:33.000Z"
],
```

where am i going wrong?  does this date need to be formatted somehow before I can use moment?

Comment: `moment("2019-12-25T18:37:33.000Z").fromNow()` works fine for me, that isn't where the error lies.

Answer (score 1):

So turns out adding a new Date wrapper gets this working.  But i'm not exactly sure why.  If anyone has any input, would be happy to hear.  Thanks

```
 timeLeft: moment(
          new Date(card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime)
        ).fromNow()
```

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what's going on and why `new Date` fixes it. But the issue is that `endTime` is an array. I was testing in CodePen and once I wrapped the value in `[...]` it said `a year ago`.

Comment: Mocking the *card* object `let card = {listingInfo: [{endTime: "2019-11-26T03:37:33.000Z"}]}` and using the OP code works fine, there's something else going on. ISO 8601 is supported by default by moment.js (and ECMAScript) so as long as the expression resolves to a valid timestamp, you should get a valid Date object. The only other result you should get is an invalid date if the result of the expression is an unparsable string.

Comment: @RobG unless it's a typo in the OP, the type of `endTime` is an array rather than a string. `endTime: [...]` That's what I was talking about in my comment above.

Comment: @MattU—That doesn't change anything. Even `let card = {listingInfo: [{endTime: ["2019-11-26T03:37:33.000Z"]}]}` still "works" because either moment.js stringifies the array to"2019-11-26T03:37:33.000Z" or moment.js calls `new Date(expr)`, which stringifies it. Try it or see [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) source or [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-value).

Comment: @RobG here's a CodePen that demonstrates it not working properly: https://codepen.io/meubin10/pen/gOONWoJ?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

As @RobG pointed out, this is incorrect. Sorry.

The expression you pass to `moment(card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime)` is a boolean expression, evaluating to `true` or `false`. Instead, I would filter `newData`  where `card.listingInfo` is valid like this:

```js
newData = newData.filter(card => {
    return card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0];
});
```

Then for `map` you would do:

```js
newData.map(card => ({
    timeLeft: moment(card.listingInfo[0])
})
```

Comment: If the first expression evaluates to *true*, then what is passed is the result of evaluating the second expression (regardless of whether it's truthy or falsey), which is `"2019-12-25T18:37:33.000Z"`. That is not the source of the error.

Comment: Wow, shows what I know about JS... Haha. Thanks @RobG and sorry for the incorrect "answer"...

Comment: Matt no worries at all!  and thanks for stepping in RobG.  Adding a new Date() made this work (as shown in my answer below)

Comment: Crockford calls `&&` the "guard operator", see [https://crockford.com/javascript/survey.html](https://crockford.com/javascript/survey.html) and search for guard.

Comment: That's definitely useful to know. I've just always assumed it evaluated as a boolean expression so I've always done things like `var hasData = x && x.y`. So have I been assigning `hasData` the value of `x.y` this whole time rather than `true`?,

Comment: @MattU—yes. `expression1 && expression2` returns either the value of expression1 if it's falsey (null, undefined, 0, etc.) or if it's truthy, the value of expression2, whatever that might be, truthy or falsey. It only returns `true` or `false` if the returned expression evaluates to `true` or `false`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Good to know! Now I feel the need to question my entire life as a developer.